# Catch-all Regular expression

Tags: php, regex, preg-match, catch-all

In my PHP program I have some regular expressions defined only at run-time.
How can I write a regular expression that match everything else those matches don't catch?

```
var_dump(preg_match("#^Bob$#", 'Bob'));
var_dump(preg_match("#^Alice$#", 'Alice'));
```

The regular expression I need is everything else than `^Bob$` and `^Alice$`.

I tried using

```
var_dump(preg_match("#(?(?=(^Bob$|^Alice$))|^$|.*)#", 'John'));
```

but the preg_match function gave me `Warning: preg_match(): Compilation failed: conditional group contains more than two branches at offset 27`

Answer (score 2, accepted):

You used a condition (the first group starting with `?`) with wrong syntax, thats your Warning.

But I think you don't need a conditional regex, try

```
 var_dump(preg_match("#^(?!(Bob|Alice)$).*#", 'John'));
```

I moved the Anchor `^` to the very start of the expression and `$` outside the alternation, so it is valid for both alternatives.

This regex will match every string (without newline characters), that is not only "Bob" or "Alice".